# Android SimpleDateFormat going crazy

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I'm facing a strange problem using `SimpleDateFormat` method in Android. Sometimes (very rarely) `format` method return a bad formatted date. Here is the code and below the output. Can you explain me the cause of that 0s?

Here is the code:

```
  public class MyObject{

    protected Timestamp detectionDate;

    public String getDetectionDateAsString() {
      String dateAsString =  Constant.ISO_8601_TS_DF.format(detectionDate);
      if(dateAsString.length()>19){
        logger.warn("ERROR ON FORMAT DATE");
        logger.warn("dateAsString:" + dateAsString);
        logger.warn("detectionDate:" + detectionDate);
      }
    }
  }

  public class Constant {

    public static final SimpleDateFormat ISO_8601_TS_DF = 
              new  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  }
```

Output:

```
14:35:05.150 [AsyncTask #2] WARN  i.m.t.d.o.OutcomesTableData - ERROR ON FORMAT DATE
14:35:05.150 [AsyncTask #2] WARN  i.m.t.d.o.OutcomesTableData - dateAsString:2016-0007-0001 0000:00:0000
14:35:05.151 [AsyncTask #2] WARN  i.m.t.d.o.OutcomesTableData - detectionDate:2016-07-03 12:34:27.194
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Whilst `Timestamp` is an extension of `Date` according to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html):

> The inheritance relationship between Timestamp and java.util.Date really denotes implementation inheritance, and **not** type inheritance.

To fix your issue, you could try using `Calendar` instead:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp.getTime());
String format = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I'll try your solution. Anyway i've not understood because it fails only sometimes (about 1 time every 1000).

Answer (score 0):

The `TimeStamp` class already returns a string in specified format (look at the field `TIME_FORMAT_REGEX` in `TimeStamp` class), so invoking `toString()` method will return you the string in format you wish.